Embed Powerbi Report on a New Tab
I am currently working on embedded powerbi reports on a VueJS based web app and would like to embed one of my powerbi reports in a new tab.
I've been trying to find a way to embed a Power BI report in a new tab from the current page, but I can't seem to figure out the steps. Is it really possible to embed a Power BI report in a new tab? Thank you in advance for your help!
